# A modification of a mathematica code that selects perfect square on the list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, code-review, code-request

Below is a code taken from OEIS that generates integers $n$ such that $\sigma(n)-n\mid (n-1)$.

```
Select[
    Range[2, 250]
  , Divisible[#-1, DivisorSigma[1, #]-#]& 
]
```

How can I modify this code in such a way that I only get a particular subset of the generated sequence. The subset I want to get are the perfect squares among those $n$ that are generated above.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Kuba. Sorry for my english construction. What I want to get is those $n$ generated by the code above that are perfect square.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some of the integers generated by the code above are: 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61, 64, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 81, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 121, 125, 127, 128, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157,.

Comment: From which I want to collect the perfect squares: 4, 16, 25 ...

Comment: I saw your answer. And it works. Been wondering why it works and I am so interested. Can you please explain why? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not start with them at the first place?

```
Select[Range[2, 15]^2, Divisible[# - 1, DivisorSigma[1, #] - #] &]
```

> ```
> {4, 9, 16, 25, 49, 64, 81, 121, 169}
> ```

Comment: Ah, I see the code also works. Thanks @Kuba. I just wondering why changing the range to [2,15]^2 will do the trick. I am interested to know. Can you please expalin? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JrAntalan instead of selecting from all integers we generate a sequece of perfect squares and then do your filtering.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thanks @Kuba

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
Select[Range[2, 250], 
 Divisible[# - 1, DivisorSigma[1, #] - #] && 
   Mod[Length@Divisors[#], 2] == 1 &]
```

Comment: Where is `36`? :)

Comment: @yode I believe the OP is requesting a subset of the sequence generated and not just the square numbers between 2 and 250 inclusive, else it would be easier to do `Range[2,Floor[Sqrt[250]]^2` etc. My interpretation may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks @upbdqn. I will try to run the code. An upvote for your answer.  I have another question if its okay with you. What function should I call if I want to break down the list geneated by the code into its prime factorization? Sorry I only know the basics of Mathematica.

Comment: And thank you again.

Comment: @JrAntalan `FactorInteger/@result` where `result` is your desired list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :-). Will try to use the codes now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select[Range[2, 250], EvenQ[Last[Internal`PerfectPower[#]]] &]
```

> {4,9,25,36,49,100,121,144,169,196,225}

Comment: Thanks @yode.  Indeed the code works.

Comment: An upvote for that. I have additional querry if its okay with you. Is there a function that breaks down the elements of the list into its prime factorizarion? Sorry I just only know simple mathematica codes.

Comment: @JrAntalan [`FactorInteger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorInteger.html)