# Help in performing computation over a list

Tags: code-review, code-request

I need to compute the quotient $\frac{n-1}{\sigma(n)-n}$ over the list say $\{9,25,49,81,121,169,...\}$ where $\sigma(.)$ is the classic sum of divisor function.

I tried to use the following codes but it did not work:

```
((n-1)/(DivisorSigma[1,n]-n))/@\{9,25,49,81,121,169,...\}
```

What must be the correct code so that I can compute the stated quotient over the given list. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need `n` to be `#` and `&` at the end of the function, like in your recent question [139430](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139430/5478)...

Comment: See [ref/Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and linked topics

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. @Kuba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have applied to the list is not a function. You can do either of the following:

```
(*1*)
((#-1)/(DivisorSigma[1,#]-#))&/@{9,25,49,81,121,169}
(*2*)
Function[n, ((n - 1)/(DivisorSigma[1, n] - n))] /@ {9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169}
(*3*)
f[n_] := ((n - 1)/(DivisorSigma[1, n] - n));
f /@ {9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169}
```